# Viewing all descendant files in TFS/VS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Is it possible to see all descendant files in the marked folder in the Source Control Explorer window in Visual Studio?

Other source control software I have used have this option, and it makes it very easy to iterate through all the files in a folder recursively and see what has changed.

Answer (score 1):

I think TFS does not support this feature, but there are others options available :

- **Pending Changes**
  You don't need to iterate through all the files to see what has changed. You can view easily what has changed using `Pending changes`. A pending change is a change (Add, Edit, Delete ...) that has not been check-in in TFS. You can view these changes for a single directory or the whole Project. In addition, you can check-in pending changes only for one directory. You will always see the summary window to view all changes before. Right-click the item (Folder or File), and you will see options : Check in, Undo or Shelve.  More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181409%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
- **File & Folder Comparison**
  In Source Control Explorer, you can compare the differences between two server folders, two local folders, or a server folder and a local folder. Simply right click on the target folder. It's quite a powerfull feature when you know it.
  Read more[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385986.aspx).